# matplotlib printing image in 2 different ways

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 2 images, one is called simply "image" and the other is called "predicted image".

They are both 28 by 28 matrices.
This is what happens when I plot "image" using

```
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

which is correct.

When I print "predicted_image" using the same snippet, it shows
[image]

I tried to then print them side by side using this code:

```
concat = numpy.concatenate((image, predicted_image), axis = 1)
plt.imshow(concat)
plt.show()
```

concat is now a 28 rows by 56 columns matrix, i expected to see the 2 images side by side. What I actually see is

[image]

I really don't understand what I did wrong. What's going on here?

Comment: Is the predicted_image correct?

Comment: Check the values of `image.dtype` and `predicted_image.dtype`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the values of the yellow area in image is much higher than all the values in predicted_image which make all the values in predicted_image have the same color level in heatmap
try combining subplots instead
[here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_and_subplots.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the buffer of the `plt` image is full when trying to show the predicted image. Try using:

```
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(predicted_image)
plt.show()
```